# Hidden screensaver does not display

Tags: screensaver

All screensavers use "-root" as part of the command, or at least that is how they are listed in kmenuedit. However none of the openGL screensavers display on screen. For example "/usr/lib/xscreensaver/glmatrix -root" runs the openGL version of the matrix screensaver. If I type that into my terminal (I am using yakuake) it runs that screensaver, but it does NOT appear on screen. When running the screensaver from systemsettings in Kubuntu 14.04, it will run in the small "display" screen so you can see what your changes in the settings are doing to it's appearance. When running the screensaver from the terminal without "-root" they run correctly in a window, yet running a test from the systemsettings I get a blank black screen with a my mouse cursor. Why won't any openGL screensavers appear on screen in kubuntu 14.04? I know it is running because when I run it in the terminal the screensaver I must stop the screensaver by using crtl-C to get my cursor back.

Comment: Where do you need to run the screensavers with the `-root` command?  I have been running the XScreensaver for years and I have never seen that.  Do you have a problem with the screensaver starting in a normal environment?  I am really having a hard time figuring out your question here.

Comment: Yes. As stated before:"When running the screensaver from the terminal without "-root" they run correctly in a window, yet running a test from the systemsettings I get a blank black screen with a my mouse cursor. "

Comment: In other words running the screen saver in the normal fashion, either from the screensaver settings OR by typing in the command in a terminal the thing never displays. The screensaver appears, but IN a window, not full screen, if I test the setting of the screensaver. If i don't use -root in the terminal which is the command line switch the used when run by the systems screensaver settings, it runs, but in the background. which I can tell by using ps -A.

Comment: Only difference between using the -root switch in the terminal and in the settings is that when in settings I get a black screen and my cursor still exists, and using the -root switch in the terminal the screen still shows my apps but the screensaver is running so I can not click the apps. when I do the screensaver in the background goes aways and seconds later I can click the apps.